# Kendo UI licencing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, kendo-ui, telerik-mvc

Does anyone have experience with Kendo UI licensing? I'm an MVC developer working on a team, if I purchased a single developer licence could I use it in our projects if I was the only dev using Kendo? or would every developer need to have a licence?

Many thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the  [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more.

Comment: That's fine, understandable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote from the [License agreement](https://www.kendoui.com/purchase/license-agreement/kendo-ui-web-commercial.aspx):

> 1.1.1 Developer License Grant. If You purchase a Developer License, Your Licensed Developers may use the Software in source and minified
>   form in the development of Your Integrated Products.
>
> For purposes of this Agreement:
>
> “Your Integrated Products” are limited to those software applications
>   which: (i) are developed by Your Licensed Developers; (ii) add
>   substantial functionality beyond the functionality provided by the
>   incorporated components of the Software; and (iii) are not commercial
>   alternatives for, or competitive in the marketplace with, the Software
>   or any components of the Software.
>
> “Licensed Developers” (i) are limited to the number of Your employees
>   or contractors authorized by You to use the Software to develop
>   software specifically for You and (ii) must correspond to the maximum
>   number of seats You have purchased from Telerik hereunder. This means
>   that, at any given time, the number of Licensed Developers cannot
>   exceed the number of seats that You have purchased from Telerik and
>   for which you have paid Telerik all applicable License Fees pursuant
>   to this Agreement. The Software is in “use” on a computer when it is
>   loaded into temporary memory (i.e. RAM) or installed into permanent
>   memory (e.g. hard disk or other storage device). Your Licensed
>   Developers may install the Software on multiple machines, so long as
>   the Software is not being used simultaneously for development purposes
>   at any given time by more Licensed Developers than You have Seats.

So basically only developers that have a developer license could use it.

Comment: Hi Darin, so if I purchase a licence I can use it in collaborative projects provided I'm the only one using the Kendo UI software? thanks

Comment: I don't quite understand how a project can be collaborative if you are the only developer :-) Who are you collaborating with? If there are other developers working on this project you need a license for them as well. It's as simple as that.

Comment: It would be a team of devs, so this is a no go - oh well! thanks

Comment: Did you know that [`there is also`](http://www.kendoui.com/download.aspx) an Open Source GPL v3 license?

Comment: I saw that, unfortunately I was looking at the DataVis package not the "Web"